# Deleting an Object using Parse - Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hey guys i am having some trouble deleting an object in parse, my application is basically to allow a user to log in and then add, delete and select a course. However my current problem is every time i click on the "delete button" it always bring up the toast message "no course was found" which i have set up to display when the object does not exist. However i have made sure that it does exist in my parse database.

This is my table in parse: http://gyazo.com/028cd4816eea96dd9364fc4fbc9fdf76

This is my code when the OnClick listener is pressed for the delete button:

```
//set onclick listener for delete button
    deleteCourse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View deletePromptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.delete_prompt, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            //set the Alert Dialog builder to the delete prompt layout file
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(deletePromptsView);

            final EditText deleteUserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDeleteTextUserInput);

            //set the dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    //get the user input and send it to parse to delete the object from the table
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Course");
                    //query.whereEqualTo("name", deleteUserInput.getText().toString());
                    query.getInBackground("name",new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                            if (object == null){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Course Was Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else{
                                object.remove(deleteUserInput.getText().toString());
                                object.deleteInBackground();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            //Create the alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            //show the alert dialog
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this code it works fine for me

```
reject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // for accepting and deleting the request all the common request
               ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Constants.REQUEST);
               query.whereEqualTo(Constants.REQUEST_NAME, "" + requestName);
               query.whereEqualTo(Constants.PLAYER_NAME, "" + rUserName);
               query.setLimit(2000);
               query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {
                          Message.message(ReplyActivity.this,""+ results.size());
                          for (ParseObject reply : results) {
                               reply.deleteInBackground();                      

                    }
                          Intent intent =new Intent(ReplyActivity.this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
                           startActivity(intent);
                           finish();
                          } else {
                            Message.message(ReplyActivity.this, "Unsuccesfull in deleting request message");
                          }

                }
            });
        }
    });
```